# Hash Define in objective C and usage in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macros

There is a thing that while defining macro's i was using a objective c file.
Lets say i define a macro as

```
#define TRY_THIS  @"try_this"
```

Then i am using this macro to save a string in Swift file in **defaults**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("12", forKey: TRY_THIS )
```

As i know, while compiling, macros just replace the `TRY_THIS` to `@"try_this"`. Lets say it is replaced :-

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("12", forKey: @"try_this" )
```

But `"@"` is not used in swift , so should this give me error or not.

I am not sure.
Can anyone tell me how to use a hash define strings of objective c in swift.

I am seeing that this command is working . Can you let me know why?

Also to get the value back i am using :-

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(TRY_THIS)

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("try_this")
```

Both should work while getting value back.
If yes why. if not why ?

Please clarify my confusion.

Comment: @EICaptain, I know this will work but  i am maintaining an objective c .h file for constants, i don't want to change it to swift

Comment: If `#define TRY_THIS  @"try_this"` is in an Objective-C header file which is included from the bridging header file, then it is imported to Swift as a `String` variable. So  `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("12", forKey: TRY_THIS )` should just work. – What is your problem?

Comment: @MartinR Can you please let me know why is it working and I have changed the question a bit . Can you look at it again